# Is it appropriate that an Asker answered his own question based on someone's else answer on the same question?

Tags: discussion

I am wondering if it is appropriate that an Asker answered his own question based on someone's else answer on the same question. It happened to me in [this question](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/200125/get-raster-centroid-using-arcpy/200170#200170).

I answered the question and the code worked properly as I tested it on my own data before submitting my answer. The code simply read the raster file and create a centroid point shapefile that has same name of the raster file. The asker mentioned that he had a problem with the code, but the problem is actually in the raster file name - the whole name is numbers (based on his comment), and I advised him that shapefile cannot start with numbers.

Later I found he copied my code and modify it a little bit of less than 10% modification. Then accepted his own answer and users upvote his answer which is actually based on my answer.

Is that action is acceptable? As far as I understand, users who answer questions try to guide the askers to solve their problem, but not to copy the answer and credit it to himself.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I think it is OK to post an answer which is a final code snippet based, even heavily, on another answer, as long as that help is credited, and it directly answers the original question.

However, since the acceptance checkmark is meant to be for the answer that helped the asker the most, I think your answer should have received the green tick and top slot.

In response to a comment:

> So what would be an appropriate action in this case? My preference
>   would be commenting to the OPs self-answer; I've suggested in a
>   similar case that they edit their original question with a 'solution'
>   section and accept the other answer ...

... I do not think a solution/answer should ever be included in a question, because questions are the area reserved for asking, while answers are the areas intended for providing answers.  Self-answering is fine and encouraged.

I think this answer is in line with an earlier Meta GIS SE Q&A: [How should the question asker post the eventual solution they used if they based it on an accepted answer?](https://gis.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/801/how-should-the-question-asker-post-the-eventual-solution-they-used-if-they-based)

Comment: So what would be an appropriate action in this case? My preference would be commenting to the OPs self-answer; I've suggested in a similar case that they edit their original question with a 'solution' section and accept the other answer ...

Comment: @Simbamangu I do not think the inclusion of a solution/answer in a question should ever be done - that is what answers are for and self-answering is fine and encouraged.

Comment: Understood, but often the answer which you accept gets you *partway* to a solution to your particular problem, by giving imprecise but worthwhile directions, and I think it's sometimes worth following up with, __in brief__, the *specific* solution.

Comment: @Simbamangu Following up with the specific solution as an answer is fine - just not as an "answer within a question".

Comment: Here I put the result of an answer in my question crediting who lead me to the result : http://astronomy.stackexchange.com/questions/1556/convert-coordinates-between-ra-dec-and-wgs-84-srid-4326

Comment: @MagnoC What is the rationale for placing an answer in the area reserved for questions when there is nothing stopping you, and it is encouraged, to answer your own questions in the area reserved for answers?

Comment: Well. Agree but it is not properly an answer. I just want to share the results of the valid answer. I'm telling it in the post. No one complains at all...

Comment: @MagnoC in your example the question had an answer but if what you did was encouraged then it would likely lead to more technically unanswered questions and potential voting confusion e.g. "I like the question but I could never vote for it with that answer in it". I recommend providing all answers as answers.